# "refresh_token" disappeared from the response in request to refresh token

Tags: google-bigquery

I found an issue that "refresh_token" disappeared from the response in this request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=***' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=***' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=***
```

My response looks like:

```
{
    "access_token": "---",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "id_token": "---"
}
```

but I had "refresh_token" in this response before. Can you say why? Thanks!